# Disable Screen Mirroring Keystroke

Tags: mac, keyboard, display

When I'm stumbling around trying to find the keystroke for lowering the screen brightness in quarter-segments (which happens to be <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness-down (F1)</kbd>), I usually wind up hitting <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness-down</kbd>, which puts my multi-monitor setup into mirrored mode, thus messing up my window arrangement and sizing.

I'd like to turn off this keystroke (which is, specifically, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness-down</kbd> and definitely *not* <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. If someone can come up with a way to permanently disable display mirroring under all circumstances, I'll probably put together a bounty for you.

I'm running OS X Lion on a sufficiently recent MacBook Pro.

> I'm not sure why they include mirrored mode in modern computers, anyway. It's never useful and it only confuses people. Don't tell me it's for presentations: any decent presentation software will have a presenter mode that everyone should learn to use and love.

Comment: I recommend you try Stay (google "stay for mac"). It's a great tool for setting default placements for windows, and being able to set all windows to their default across multiple monitors with one click. Might help with the window arrangement problem

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX I could, but the window arrangement isn't the problem. The problem is the fact that I can accidentally turn on mirrored mode with a single keystroke.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX And, actually, it's just proof that almost every one of my apps is written incorrectly (Chrome, Eclipse, Java, Firefox, VMware Fusion, Outlook, a few others) because they all stay resized in the wrong part of the screen but the Terminal realizes what went on and moves back to where it's supposed to be.

Comment: I guess enabling "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard keys" in Keyboard preferences would be even worse, right?

Comment: In re the mouse-over gripe: I use a dual-display Mac all day, but when I have a student or a faculty member sit next to me so I can demonstrate something on the screen, switching to mirrored mode so they don't have to lean over my lap is priceless. Why the function needs to be triggered by a key combo, though, is mysterious.

Comment: @Thecafremo That actually *would* help, as then I'd have to hit Command-Fn-F1 instead of just Command-F1, but I change my brightness settings about twenty times every day, so it's be really annoying to have to use Fn-F1 to do so.

Comment: @CajunLuke That's why I thought it would be even worse, changing a nuisance for another.

Comment: I use mirror mode ALL THE TIME. Extended desktop splits my VRAM in half for each display. Mirror mode makes graphics-intensive apps run much more smoothly while still getting the GUI on the big display.

Comment: @iynque How do you tell how it splits your VRAM? Activity Monitor doesn't seem to include VRAM metrics.

Comment: @CajunLuke In looking for a source, now I'm not so sure. Some still claim Mac OS X splits the VRAM between displays, but others say that OS X started dynamically allocating VRAM as far back as 10.4. Still, with an extended desktop the resources are split, even if it's not split in half. It has a noticeable effect when using 3D modeling software, games, and some high resolution video playback.

Comment: @CajunLuke I use screen mirroring frequently. Any time I can't see the projected screen that I'm working on, or it's too far away for me to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an entry for the shortcut in [com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785). The media keys cannot be configured in DefaultKeyBinding.dict or keylayout files. I didn't find any hidden preferences with strings either.

I was able to disable it with KeyRemap4MacBook, but only on my laptop's keyboard; not on an Apple Wireless Keyboard.

1. Save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
       <name>Disable Command-F1</name>
       <identifier>private.disable.command.f1</identifier>
       <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
       <autogen>--ConsumerToConsumer-- ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```
2. Press the ReloadXML button and enable the new remapping in the first tab

Comment: I was able to get it to work for the wireless keyboard by using `__KeyToKey__` instead of `--ConsumerToConsumer--` and `KeyCode` instead of `ConsumerKeyCode`

Comment: Does anyone know how to get this set up in Karabiner-Elements?

Comment: @benregn I added an answer that shows how to disable the mirror keyboard shortcut using Karabiner-Elements: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459521/65944

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness-down</kbd> keyboard shortcut to mirror displays can be disabled with [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) as well. Searching for "mirror" on the [Karabiner-Elements complex_modifications rules](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=mirror), I found [Disable Cmd+F1 Toggle Screen Mirroring](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/json/disable_cmd_f1_screen_mirroring.json). Importing this JSON into Karabiner-Elements disables this shortcut effectively.